# Once again: "javac: file not found: hello.java

Tags: java

I was using Java SE Jdk1.7.0_40 and it was working perfectly fine. I've no idea what went wrong, I've set the path many times through different ways. If I check in cmd like by writing javac or java -version, it results affirmative but when i write 
**javac hello.java** i get this error..

***javac: file not found: hello.java
Usage: javac  
use -help for a list of possible options***

I went through almost all of topics related to my problem but all are saying the same thing that is "to set the path, may be your path is not correct, etc etc". I've re-install java but still no use.

Is there any step by step procedure to check whether the path is actually responding or not?

Am using Windows 7 and current version of Java is SE jdk1.7.0_60

a thing more.. when I compile the java file from the folder containing that file, it works fine and generate .class file but when I execute the class file .. 
**java hello** , i get this

***Error: Could not find or load main class hello***

may be i'm missing something..

Help...

Comment: Please share structure of your project, where do you run `javac` and exact command line.

Comment: have you tried javac command for other files too ?

Comment: Is there a file named "hello.java" in the directory from which you're executing the command?

Comment: `javac: file not found: hello.java Usage: javac use -help for a list of possible options` Clearly this error has ***nothing*** to do with your system path, as the `javac` binary is found and works. It can't find your `hello.java` file.

Comment: Is the class hello in the default package?

Comment: @Jens: That's irrelevant - it can't find the source file to start with.

Comment: if i run javac from current directory, it compiles the java file but again when i run java cmd it generates another error as i describe above

Comment: Your "a thing more" actually changed your question. It means that you *can* compile your class but cannot run it. Does your class contain main method?

Comment: @ AlexR.. yes it contains main method

Comment: @AlexR.. sorry for this but am completely exhausted its been more than 5 days that am horribly stuck at this point..

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem with `javac` not being on your `PATH`, since the error you see is an error *from* `javac`, which could only occur if `javac`is on your path and running.

The only possibility is that `hello.java` is not in the **current working directory** from which you are invoking the command. Putting the directory that `hello.java` lives in onto your `PATH` will not help here.